# Drag and Drop issue with Anypoint Studio

Tags: anypoint-studio

I am new to Mule and Anypoint Studio (64bit Version: 5.2.0), I can't add "Byte Array to String" transformer using drag and drop.[image]

Comment: Drag and drop is working fine only when source component placed into target region area.

Answer (score 0):

Validate your `<%installation_Direcotry%>/AnypointStudio.ini` for assigned memory, it should be :

```
-Xms584m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:MaxPermSize=784m
```

Answer (score 0):

First check you assigned memory by checking the <%installation_Direcotry%>/AnypointStudio.ini file in case your studio gets hanged.

If it is ok then you have multiple options to place to place a processor in palette.

1. select the transformer in the palette then drag & drop it to the process area where you want to put the transformer.
2. select the transformer in the palette then directly click on the process area where you want to put the transformer.you don't need to drag & drop.
3. you can also write the xml configuration for the same just by pressing ctrl + space options that would pop-up the list of components.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

You have to drop the 'Byte Array to String' transformed within the 'Process' box of the flow, not outside it.